# QfileSystemWatcher doesn't work

Tags: qt, filesystems, filesystemwatcher

This is how I am initializing the watcher:

```
  QFileSystemWatcher watcher;
  bool isWatched = watcher.addPath("../stylesheets/main.style");
  if (isWatched) qDebug() << "Stylesheet is being watched.";
  connect(&watcher, &QFileSystemWatcher::fileChanged, this, &PCLViewer::updateStyle );
```

But my update style function never gets called, when I modify, delete or rename the file! I've also tried connecting the slots and signals like this:

```
connect(&watcher, SIGNAL(fileChanged(QString)), this, SLOT(updateStyle(QString)) );
```

The signature for the `updateStyle` functions is this:

```
public slots:
    void updateStyle(const QString &path);
```

I'm using ubuntu.

Comment: The code fragments look correct, so far. Please post a more complete example of your code.

Comment: did you try to use a full path to the file?

Comment: Yes I tired full path and also another file, but neither worked!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The slot function signature was wrong. I had to use `void updateStyle (QString path);` for it to get called.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is having the same problem.

Try this:

```
QFileSystemWatcher *watcher = new QFileSystemWatcher();
bool beingWatched = watcher->addPath("Enter your path here");
if (beingWatched ) qDebug() << "Being watched";
QObject::connect(watcher, SIGNAL(fileChanged(QString)), this, SLOT(handleFileChanged(QString)));
```

I don't know why but you need to create a pointer, at least on my system, to emit a signal or it won't work.

Comment: In the OP you didn't use a pointer so the object deleted itself when it lost scope (hard to say from the snippet when that would have been). Using the pointer the object is on the heap and would not be deleted, ever in this case. Typically you would use the parent syntax:

     QFileSystemWatcher *watcher = new QFileSystemWatcher(this);

So the object will get destroyed when the parent is destroyed.

ps. i only answered this old msg because I am having issues with QFileSystemWatcher and this was the first google result for my issue which is not related as it turns out.